# Print Stack Exchange question to PDF

Tags: support, printing

Once upon a time... there was this website to print a Stack Exchange question to PDF [`http://www.stackprinter.com/`](http://www.stackprinter.com/). It appears to me it's not working anymore. Are there any similar sites?

[image]

Comment: It appears to still work for me; is there something on it that appears to be broken?

Comment: What "does not work" for you? Do you receive a 404 error and the page doesn't load? Please add some details that highlight your problem. This may include your browser specifications.

Comment: Working for me. [Check this](http://isup.me/http://www.stackprinter.com/).

Comment: I'd wonder if it's blocked in your hosts file...because I can access it, both on my cellular telephone and on my portable computer. If you have a smartphone, can you try visiting the site on that?

Comment: @m0nhawk - nice link thks!

Comment: For me it was REALLY slow (2 minutes to load) but not broken. Probably some slow server somewhere in the middle breaking things up.